# Why does the function returns 'undefined undefined' instead of name (James Bond)? Its a JS code

Tags: javascript, function, output

```
function Person(first, last) {
    return {
        first: first,
        last: last,
        fullName: function() {
            return this.first + ' ' + this.last;
        },
        fullNameReversed: function() {
            return this.last + ', ' + this.first;
        }
    };
}
p = Person("James", "Bond");
var fullName = p.fullName;
fullName();
```

I was expecting Output = **'James Bond'** but get **'undefined undefined'**

Comment: No need for `this`. `fullName: () => { return first + ' ' + last; }`

Comment: Can you explain the reason please @Jaun Mendes

Comment: @VishalGupta because the name is Bond, James Bond  (if you know what I mean)

Comment: When you assign `p.fullname` to a variable it loses the `this` context. `this` is set on method invocation, and is set to the object upon which you call the method. Eg. `p.fullname()` would set `this` in `fullname` to `p`. When you store the method in a variable and then call it by itself `fullname()`, `this` will be set to `undefined` when in strict mode, or to the global object `window` when not in strict mode. If you want to use `fullname` as a function you could define it as such: `var fullname = () => p.fullname`.

Comment: Note that the comment of Juan does also solve the issue, but if you are re-assigning the `first` or `last` properties of `p`, the `fullname` method won't produce a new output. eg. `p = Person("James", "Bond")`, then `p.first = "John"`, then `p.fullname() //=> "James Bond"` This is because `fullName: () => first + ' ' + last` uses the constructor params, not the current object properties.

Comment: My first comment has a typo `var fullname = () => p.fullname` is missing one set of parentheses and should be `var fullname = () => p.fullname()`.

Comment: function Person(first, last, mid) {
    middle = mid;
    return {
        first: first,
        last: last,
        fullName: function() {
            return this.first + ' ' + this.last + ' ' + this.middle;
        },
        fullNameReversed: function() {
            return this.last + ', ' + this.first;
        }
    };
}
p = Person("James", "Bond", "Mega");
var fullName = p.fullName;
fullName(); But in this case middle returns correctly. Reason?

Comment: `middle` is an implicit global. Therefore when `this = window`, you are accessing `window.middle`.

Comment: @VishalGupta Because `middle = mid`—without `let`, `const` or `var`—will set `window.middle = mid`. So when you call `fullname()` and you are not in strict mode, `window` is passed as `this`. Therefore `this.middle` will correctly access the value. Note that you run into issues when you would create multiple people, because they all share the same global `window.middle`. `p1 = Person("James", "Bond", "Mega")`, `p2 = Person("John", "Doe", "Peta")`, `const fullname = p1.fullname`, `fullname() //=> "undefined Peta undefined"`

Comment: Thanks guys. I think I understood. So basically p.fullName assigns a function and not the object p and middle is a global variable and thus is accessed via window. Let me know if this is wrong.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Correct, only at the moment of method invocation (when you use parentheses to call the method) is `this` assigned.

Comment: Vishal, because you are not depending on `this`, you are just using the closure variables. It's a workaround for the `this` problem.